# Php / Laravel multiple file uploading error - undefined offset

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a bit new to multiple file uploads and I have an error in which 2 of my fields are optional. I tried to test what if my client uploaded on primary image and Image 3 fields, then when it submitted the form error appeared .
it says **Undefined offset: 2** in my code `"Image::make($file)->resize(450,450)->save('storage/uploads/'.$fileToStore[$key],50);"`

**Here is my fields**

```
<label for="">Primary Image </label>
<input type="file" name="prod_image[]" accept="image/*" required>

<label for="">Image 2 (Optional) </label>
<input type="file" name="prod_image[]" accept="image/*">

<label for="">Image 3 (Optional) </label>
<input type="file" name="prod_image[]" accept="image/*">
```

**Here is my code in backend.**

```
$files = $request->prod_image;

//set new filename and upload to /storage/uploads/
foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileToArray[] = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 _ .-]/', '', $request->prod_name)).'-'.generate_random_str(10).'.'.$extension;
    $implodeFile = implode(',', $fileToArray);
    $fileToStore = explode(',', $implodeFile);

    Image::make($file)->resize(450,450)->save('storage/uploads/'.$fileToStore[$key],50);
}
$insert = $this->productData($request);
$getInsertedId = DB::table('products')->insertGetId($insert);

//insert to product_image table
for($i = 0; $i < count($fileToStore); $i++) {
   DB::table('product_image')->insert(['product_id' => $getInsertedId,'product_image' => $fileToStore[$i]]);
}
```

What to do in order to insert all the uploaded images and also the data to my product_image table even they skipped / forgot to put image on Image 2 field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem, so instead of using $key in my foreach in which it check every key of my field. 
I set a $initKey = 0 in order to use it for $fileToStore and increment it. I don't know if this is the best way but it solves my problem. Sorry for my poor explanation I'm not good at It.

**Here's my code**

```
$files = $request->prod_image;
$initKey = 0;
foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileToArray[] = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 _ .-]/', '', $request->prod_name)).'-'.generate_random_str(10).'.'.$extension;
    $implodeFile = implode(',', $fileToArray);
    $fileToStore = explode(',', $implodeFile);

    Image::make($file)->resize(450,450)->save('storage/uploads/'.$fileToStore[$initKey],50);
    $initKey++;
}
$insert = $this->productData($request);
$getInsertedId = DB::table('products')->insertGetId($insert);

for($i = 0; $i < count($fileToStore); $i++) {
   DB::table('product_image')->insert(['product_id' => $getInsertedId,'product_image' => $fileToStore[$i]]);
}
```